# Vue transitions for dynamic components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, css-transitions

i'm tryin to trigger an animation when a dynamic component change but it doesn't work i appreciate any advice, thanks!

Here's my code:

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
 <keep-alive>
  <Component
   :is="camposForm[campoActual].componente"
   :label="camposForm[campoActual].label"
  />
 </keep-alive>
</transition>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all .9s;
    }
    .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to  {
        transform: translateY(3px);
        opacity: 0;
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: what is the issue you are having, your code seems to be fine, you can see the animation working here https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-glitter-qkqqp

Comment: My code is exactly like that but the animation doesn't work. It seems that I have to investigate further why it does not work for me, thanks for your time!

Comment: have you checked the example I provided, which might help you find what is the issue.